# My Python script can't access to internet using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a script that is concerned with accessing the internet, but it doesn't work. My connection to the internet is stable and the rest of the script works perfectly. I've used selenium module to do so.
Please look into the script I've attached and let me know if there are any problems and how I could resolve those.

```
def search_web(input): 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(1) 
driver.maximize_window() 

if 'youtube' in input.lower(): 

    assistant_speaks("Opening in youtube") 
    indx = input.lower().split().index('youtube') 
    query = input.split()[indx + 1:] 
    driver.get("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query =" + '+'.join(query)) 
    return

elif 'wikipedia' in input.lower(): 

    assistant_speaks("Opening Wikipedia") 
    indx = input.lower().split().index('wikipedia') 
    query = input.split()[indx + 1:] 
    driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + '_'.join(query)) 
    return

else: 

    if 'google' in input: 

        indx = input.lower().split().index('google') 
        query = input.split()[indx + 1:] 
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q =" + '+'.join(query)) 

    elif 'search' in input: 

        indx = input.lower().split().index('google') 
        query = input.split()[indx + 1:] 
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q =" + '+'.join(query)) 

    else: 

        driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q =" + '+'.join(input.split())) 

    return
```

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Please print what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding executable_path to chrome driver. I ran with `executable_path`, it's working fine for me.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path_of_chrome_driver')
```

Comment: I wrote this in my script: driver = `webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\Shishir Modi\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")`

Comment: But it still gives this error: `File "C:\Users\Shishir Modi\Desktop\Shishir\Basics\Test.py", line 4
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\Shishir Modi\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
                                              ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`